# How do I access a PHP file hosted on a server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-hosting

I have an android app which connects to a hosted db to fetch data.

When testing on localhost, it was working all fine.

I moved the db to a hosted server, a couple of days back and while trying to run the app, it is throwing error while fetching data from db.

ERROR:

`08-19 06:57:28.579: E/JSON Parser(32067): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

`<!DOCTYPE` is not a value in any of the tables in the database (I've checked and double checked). Instead, `<!DOCTYPE` is the first line in the 'index.html' file which is also hosted on the same server.

The url being used by the app is: `http://ipaddress/filename.php`.

While reading the documentation provided by the web hosting company, I remember reading something which said that 'the server treats the index.html as the home page or default page for this directory'. Basically when I type 'www.someaddress.com' or its IP, it returns index.html. I am guessing that when the app pings the IP address provided in the url, index.html file is being returned (is it even possible?).

The question is, how do I go around this problem? Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quite likely, you don't request the right script. Print the returned data on the android device to view returned data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My guess was right: the index.html file was being returned and the json parsor was trying to convert it to jsonobject and hence the error.

But this was happening due to another problems which I should have checked:

The android app was using `http://ipaddress/filename.php` for fetching the data from server. When I tried to use the same url on a browser it returned `403 forbidden`. I replaced the url with `www.sitename.com/filename.php` and it returned a json response as expected.

After replacing all the urls in the app to match `www.sitename.com/filename.php` instead of `http://ipaddress/filename.php`, it started fetching data properly.

For some reason, when I used `http://sitename.com/filename.php` in the android app, it was also returning index.html. I had to replace all `http://` with `www.` to get it to work.

Thanks SteAp for your help!